# tsql list of dates to date ranges

Tags: t-sql, pivot-table, common-table-expression, group-by

I am trying to generate an item, date range summary from a list of item, date(s) for sql-2008.

```
DECLARE @RoomDays AS TABLE (
    [RoomID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DateOf] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Segment] [char](1) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @RoomDays
VALUES 
('1','2013-07-03','1'),
('1','2013-07-04','1'),
('1','2013-07-05','6'),
('1','2013-07-15','6'),
('1','2013-07-16','6'),
('2','2013-07-08','1'),
('2','2013-07-09','1'),
('2','2013-07-10','6'),
('2','2013-07-11','6'),
('2','2013-07-12','1'),
('2','2013-07-13','1'),
('3','2013-07-19','6')
```

The results I am trying to get:

```
RoomID  DateFrom    DateThru    Segments     NumDays
1       2013-07-03  2013-07-05  1,1,6        3
1       2013-07-15  2013-07-16  6,6          2
2       2013-07-08  2013-07-13  1,1,6,6,1,1  6
3       2013-07-19  2013-07-19  6            1
```

I just can not get my head around how to do this ...

..maybe this for the Segments column:

```
( 
SELECT CAST( ltrim(rtrim(SegmentID)) + ', ' AS VARCHAR(MAX))
from @RoomDays where roomid = rd.roomid
FOR XML PATH ('')
)+' ' as Segments,
--
```

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to find info on "Gaps and Islands".

Comment: How to distinguish between 1st and 2nd row in results, since id is the same?

Comment: I made a blogpost in may about this stuff. The article is in swedish here: http://blogs.solidq.com/SQL-Server-pa-svenska/Post.aspx?ID=24&title=Hur+konkatenering+med+FOR+XML+PATH+fungerar. I ran it through google translate and it turned out ok-ish (word of warning, overlapping words in english and swedish might have been translated inside the code). Check that out here : http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=sv&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fblogs.solidq.com%2FSQL-Server-pa-svenska%2FPost.aspx%3FID%3D24%26title%3DHur%2Bkonkatenering%2Bmed%2BFOR%2BXML%2BPATH%2Bfungerar.

Answer (score 0):

Getting date ranges is the age old Gaps and Islands problem.
Concatenating your segments is done with the XML trick like you described.

Here is a complete solution with an SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d4a961/11

Using your code in the question and a table variable the code should look like this:

```
WITH groupedDays AS (
SELECT
RoomID
,DateOf
,Segment
,DATEADD(day,-row_number() OVER (partition by RoomID order by DateOf),DateOf) AS Island
FROM @RoomDays
)

SELECT
outerTable.RoomID
,MIN(outerTable.DateOf) AS DateFrom
,MAX(outerTable.DateOf) AS DateThru
,STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + innerTable.Segment
    FROM groupedDays AS innerTable
    WHERE innerTable.RoomID = outerTable.RoomID
    AND innerTable.Island = outerTable.Island
    ORDER BY innerTable.DateOf
    FOR XML PATH('')
),1,1,'')
,COUNT(*) AS NumDays

FROM groupedDays AS outerTable

GROUP BY
outerTable.RoomID
,outerTable.Island

ORDER BY
outerTable.RoomID
,outerTable.Island
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below is full working example with your sample data and here are some useful links:

[T-SQL CSV from column values](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/11/25/sql-server-comma-separated-values-csv-from-table-column/)

[Recursive CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

    DECLARE @RoomDays TABLE 
    (
         [RoomID] INT NOT NULL
        ,[DateOf] DATE NOT NULL
        ,[Segment] CHAR(1) NOT NULL
    )

    INSERT INTO @RoomDays ([RoomID], [DateOf], [Segment] )
    VALUES   ('1','2013-07-03','1')
            ,('1','2013-07-04','1')
            ,('1','2013-07-05','6')
            ,('1','2013-07-15','6')
            ,('1','2013-07-16','6')
            ,('2','2013-07-08','1')
            ,('2','2013-07-09','1')
            ,('2','2013-07-10','6')
            ,('2','2013-07-11','6')
            ,('2','2013-07-12','1')
            ,('2','2013-07-13','1')
            ,('3','2013-07-19','6')

    ;WITH DataSource ([RoomID], [DateOf], [Segment], [Level]) AS
    (
        SELECT [RoomID], [DateOf], [Segment], 0 AS [Level] 
        FROM @RoomDays AS RD
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT RD1.[RoomID], RD1.[DateOf], RD1.[Segment], [Level] + 1 
        FROM @RoomDays AS RD1
        INNER JOIN DataSource DS
            ON RD1.RoomID = DS.RoomID
        WHERE DATEADD (DAY , 1 , DS.DateOf) =  RD1.DateOf 
    ),
    StartDates AS
    (
        -- Retriving the "Start" records
        SELECT [RoomID], [DateOf], [Segment]
        FROM DataSource
        WHERE [Level] = 0
        EXCEPT
        SELECT [RoomID], [DateOf], [Segment]
        FROM DataSource
        WHERE [Level] = 1
    ),
    TempResult AS
    (
        -- Mathing each "Start" record with its values
        SELECT  SD.[DateOf] AS [StartDate]
               ,RD.[RoomId]
               ,RD.[DateOf]
               ,RD.[Segment]
        FROM StartDates SD
        INNER JOIN @RoomDays RD
            ON SD.RoomID = RD.RoomID
            AND SD.DateOf <= RD.DateOf      
            AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM StartDates WHERE DateOf <= RD.DateOf AND RoomID = RD.RoomID AND SD.DateOf < DateOf)
    )
    SELECT TR.[RoomID]  AS [RoomID]
          ,MIN(TR.[DateOf]) AS [DateFrom]
          ,MAX(TR.[DateOf]) AS [DateThru]
          ,SUBSTRING((SELECT ',' + [Segment] FROM TempResult WHERE [StartDate] = TR.[StartDate] FOR XML PATH('')),2,4000) AS CSV
          ,COUNT(TR.[DateOf]) AS [NumDays]
    FROM TempResult TR
    GROUP BY TR.[RoomID],TR.[StartDate]

SET NOCOUNT OFF
GO
```

OUTPUT:

```
1   2013-07-03  2013-07-05  1,1,6   3
1   2013-07-15  2013-07-16  6,6 2
2   2013-07-08  2013-07-13  1,1,6,6,1,1 6
3   2013-07-19  2013-07-19  6   1
```

Please, note that the code above can be put into view or function, or you can "cut" it and save the results from each CTE in temp or table variable tables.